Is the number of hydrogen atoms always the same for saturated compounds?
For alkanes that have only carbon-hydrogen single bonds, it seems that despite the structure, isomers always have the same number of hydrogen atoms. I have tried this on isomers that have various branches and chains and it seems to hold. Is there a general way to prove or understand why this is?

Yes, provided they don't have cycles.

C forms 4 bonds is "why this is". If branching decreases the H on one of the C it increases the H on the other C

Also, isn't this the definition of isomerism? Chemical compounds that have the same molecular formula but different spatial arrangements of atoms—of course the number of hydrogens is the same as the "unbranched" structure.


What is the electronic configuration of an isolated carbon atom, and the one of an isolated hydrogen atom?  2) What does the (formal) hybridization to yield degenerate sp³ orbitals of carbon atoms imply for their number at disposition? 3) The general sum formula of $\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$ for non-cyclic alkanes is mentioned right in the beginning of Wikipedia's article.


Take an acyclic alkane. One by one, remove $\ce{-CH3}$ groups (from the end of chains) and replace them with a hydrogen, effectively removing  $\ce{CH2}$ units. After you removed all carbons, you are left with dihydrogen. Tallying all the atoms, you get the formula $\ce{H-(CH2)_n-H}$, i.e. always the same number of hydrogen atoms for a given number of carbon atoms, no matter how the molecule was branched.

Yes. Provided they don’t have cycles. As for a proof, consider a saturated and non-cyclic alkane with n carbon atoms. Each carbon atom forms 4 bonds. If a Carbon bonds to 0 other carbons, it has 4 hydrogens, if it bonds to 1C is has 3H, if it bonds to 2C it has 2H, if it bonds to 3C it has 1H and if it bonds to 4C it has 0H. So letting the number of 0C-bonding carbons be A, the number of 1C-bonded carbons be B and so on we gather that:
No. carbon atoms = n = A+B+C+D+E
No. hydrogens atoms = 4A+3B+2C+D+(0E)
But for n carbons you must have n-1 carbon-carbon bonds so 2(n-1) to account for double counting gives:
2n-2 = 4E+3D+2C+B+(0A)
Combining we get that:
2n-2 + No. H atoms = 4n
No. H atoms = 2n+2
Also on the subject of terminology:
An alkane only ever has carbon-carbon single bonds or carbon-hydrogen (single) bonds.
Isomers by definition have the same number of atoms.
